# Inheriting from Set.prototype

Tags: javascript, inheritance, set, ecmascript-6

This is really bugging me. I can easily create a new class that inherits methods from `Array.prototype`:

```
var MyArray = function() {};

MyArray.prototype = Array.prototype;

var myArray = new MyArray();
myArray.push(1); // this is allowed
```

The same inheritance pattern doesn't seem to work with `Set.prototype`:

```
var MySet = function() {};

MySet.prototype = Set.prototype;

var mySet = new MySet();
mySet.add(1); // TypeError: Method Set.prototype.add called on incompatible receiver
```

Is this an implementation issue? Is there another inheritance pattern that will work? I've tried this in node v0.12 and Canary with the same results.

EDIT: This solution works, but I'm still not sure why the above doesn't work the same:

```
var MySet = function(array) {
  var inst = new Set(array);
  inst.__proto__ = MySet.prototype;
  return inst;
}

MySet.prototype = Object.create(Set.prototype);
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is this an implementation issue? Is there another inheritance pattern that will work?

No, this behaviour is correct as by the spec. The `Set` methods must be invoked on actual sets (objects initialised with set-specific internal slots), and are not generic as the `Array` methods (which basically work on everything that has a `.length` property).

As [the spec states](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-set-constructor):

> The `Set` constructor is designed to be subclassable. It may be used
>   as the value in an `extends` clause of a `class` definition. Subclass
>   constructors that intend to inherit the specified `Set` behaviour must
>   include a `super` call to the `Set` constructor to create and
>   initialize the subclass instance with the internal state necessary to
>   support the `Set.prototype` built-in methods.

So you will have to use ES6 class syntax to inherit from the built-ins.

```
class MySet extends Set {} // default constructor has super() call

var mySet = new MySet();
mySet.add(1);
```

Whether this subclassing is supported depends on the implementation, not all runtimes and transpilers are ES6-compliant yet.

Comment: Surely, as subclassing is just sytanx sugar for prototypes, why can't it be done without classes?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Subclassing is not just sugar for prototypes, it's also about initialisation (in the constructor). `class` syntax [is not completely sugar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32458960/1048572), they changed the way instances are created so that it works with builtins and their internal slots now.