# What is "new.target"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The ECMAScript 2015 specification mention the keyword (or words?) ***new.target*** exactly 3 times - 1 time in [14.2.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-static-semantics-contains):

> Normally, Contains does not look inside most function forms However,
>   Contains is used to detect *new.target*, this, and super usage within an
>   ArrowFunction.

and twice in [14.2.16](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> An ArrowFunction does not define local bindings for arguments, super,
>   this, or **new.target**. Any reference to arguments, super, this, or
>   **new.target** within an ArrowFunction must resolve to a binding in a
>   lexically enclosing environment

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) mentions it, but is very vague and the page is incomplete.

Babel doesn't seem to support it. I got syntax errors when trying to use *new.target* in a function (arrow or others).

What is it, and how is it supposed to be used?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You didn't find it in the spec because in the syntax definitions it is written with blanks, as `new . target`. The name of the expression is `NewTarget`, and you'll find that term a few times around.

*NewTarget* is the first of the so-called [*meta properties*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-meta-properties) and can be found in §12.3.8.

Its sole purpose is to [retrieve](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-getnewtarget) the current value of the *[[NewTarget]]* value of the current (non-arrow) function environment. It is a value that is set when a function is called (very much like the `this` binding), and according to [§8.1.1.3 *Function Environment Records*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-environment-records):

> If this Environment Record was created by the *[[Construct]]* internal method, *[[NewTarget]]* is the value of the *[[Construct]]* `newTarget` parameter. Otherwise, its value is `undefined`.

So, for one thing, finally enables us to detect whether a function was called as a constructor or not.

But that's not its real purpose. So what is it then? It is part of the way how ES6 classes are not only syntactic sugar, and how they allow us inheriting from builtin objects. When you call a `class` constructor via `new X`, the `this` value is not yet initialised - the object is not yet created when the constructor body is entered. It does get created by the super constructor during the `super()` call (which is necessary when internal slots are supposed to be created). Still, the instance should inherit from the `.prototype` of the originally called constructor, and that's where *newTarget* comes into the play. It does hold the "outermost" constructor that received the `new` call during `super()` invocations. You can follow it all the way down in the spec, but basically it always is the `newTarget` not the currently executed constructor that does get passed into the [`OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor` procedure](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinarycreatefromconstructor) - for example in [step 5 of §9.2.2 *[[Construct]]*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget) for user-defined functions.

Long text, maybe an example is better suited:

```
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        // implicit (from the `super` call)
        //    new.target = Child;
        // implicit (because `Parent` doesn't extend anything):
        //    this = Object.create(new.target.prototype);
        console.log(new.target) // Child!
    }
}
class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        // `this` is uninitialised (and would throw if accessed)
        // implicit (from the `new` call):
        //    new.target = Child 
        super(); // this = Reflect.construct(Parent, [], new.target);
        console.log(this);
    }
}
new Child;
```

Comment: So that means its valid syntax to write `console.log(new . target)` (with spaces) inside a function?

Comment: @Amit: I presume - it's multiple tokens, which can always be separated via whitespace. It's valid ES to write `console . log(…)` as well :-) Of course no one does it - except for line breaks when method chaining…

Comment: but that not quite the same. `console` is an identifier, `new` is a keyword. That would make it quite odd when considering `new Obj()` is valid syntax.

Comment: "this is uninitialized (and throws)", I'm not sure what you're referring to there.

Comment: @Amit: Yes, `new.target` is not a single keyword, it's a grammar element consisting of three tokens (one keyword, a dot, and an identifier).

Comment: @Asad: You cannot access `this` before the `super()` call - when you try referencing it, it throws a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: @Bergi Ah yes, makes sense. Didn't realize you were referring to `this`.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for the elaborate answer. But I still can't get this part `this = Object.create(new.target.prototype);` - why does parent gets child prototype? `new.target` is a child as you specified

Comment: @Maximus Not *a* child, but *the* `Child` *constructor* itself. And we want the new instance to inherit from the `Child.prototype` object

Comment: Can you give a reference to the spec where Child (is actually its constructor function if I understand right) is get its [[Prototype]] (from Parent)?

Comment: @Mergasov Do you mean [*constructorParent* in step 6 of §14.5.14](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation), i.e. for `Object.getPrototypeOf(Child) === Parent`? Not sure what it has to do with this question.

Comment: @Bergi Does this mean `new.target` cannot be used to enforce the non-instantiation of an abstract class in JavaScript?

Comment: @Melab No? `if (new.target === MyAbstractClass)` is perfectly fine. (Although one might question the concept of abstract classes in general)

Answer (score 8):

It's primarily intended as a better way to detect when a constructor is called without `new`.

From http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html:

> `new.target` is an implicit parameter that all functions have. It is to constructor calls what `this` is to method calls.

So I can write:

```
function Foo() {
  if (!new.target) throw "Foo() must be called with new";
  ...
}
```

There are more details to how this works, and more contexts in which it is useful, but we'll leave it here.

For some meeting notes regarding `new.target`, see https://esdiscuss.org/notes/2015-01-27.

Comment: I think it is impossible to call a constructor without `new` (you'll get an exception). Unless by "constructor" you mean a regular function called with "new", and I'm just misunderstanding you.

Comment: @Asad A constructor **is** a regular function called with `new`.

Comment: I see. I was thinking of it in the sense of the new ES6 `constructor`-keyword constructors, which TypeError if you don't invoke them with `new`.

Comment: Where is any of this defined in the spec?

Comment: also, a constructor **is not** a regular function, and can't be called ***without*** `new`.

Comment: @Amit I'm talking about constructors in the classic sense of `function Foo()`.

Comment: Yeah, I re-read these comments, mine is pretty much what Asad already said, and you did explian yourself.

Comment: There is some information about this at http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-built-in-function-objects, but it does not directly describe `new.target`.

Comment: Regarding the example with `MyPromise.reject`, that's not what is explained in the 2ality link, and again, nothing of it in the spec. If anything, I'd expect it to have some meaningful value when constructing a new object instance (`new MyPromise.reject()`), but that's not how the typical (standard..) Promise syntax works.

Comment: Hm, that `Promise.reject` example seems to be really wrong. That function is not expected to be called as a constructor, so you should not use `new.target` at all. The correct approach is to  `return new this(…)` in static methods.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, took that out until I figure it out.