# ES6 Class extending native type makes instanceof behave unexpectedly in some JavaScript engines?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-inheritance

Consider the following ES6 Classes:

```js
'use strict';

class Dummy {
}

class ExtendDummy extends Dummy {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args)
    }
}

class ExtendString extends String {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args)
    }
}

const ed = new ExtendDummy('dummy');
const es = new ExtendString('string');

console.log(ed instanceof ExtendDummy);
console.log(es instanceof ExtendString);
```

My understanding is that both should be `true`, and in Firefox and Chrome they are, however Node says `es instanceof ExtendString` is `false`. It's the same with other constructors, not just `String`.

Software I used:

- Node v5.11.0 with the `--harmony` flag.
- Chrome 50
- Firefox 45

Which JavaScript engine is correct and why?

Comment: Node.js has older version of v8 than Chrome, so I expect bug to be in node. By the way, you can try Node.js 6.0.

Comment: Just going to repeat myself a few times here.

Comment: _"Just going to repeat myself a few times here"_ - why?

Comment: @Qwertiy Rumors of hats. Sorry for the notification.

Comment: What hat is it?

Comment: @Qwertiy Bluefeet maybe, but I haven't gotten it, so I think this was a bust.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Node appears to be incorrect, `es instanceof ExtendString` should definitely be `true` (like everyone would expect).

`String[Symbol.hasInstance]` is not overwritten, and `Object.getPrototypeOf(es)` should be `ExtendedString.prototype`, as the spec details this in the [`String (value)` function description](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string-constructor-string-value):

> 5. Return [StringCreate](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-stringcreate)(`s`, [GetPrototypeFromConstructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-getprototypefromconstructor)(NewTarget, `"%StringPrototype%"`)).

The [newtarget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32450516/1048572) refers to `ExtendString` when you construct the `new ExtendString('string')` instance, and since it is a constructor with a `.prototype` object it will use `ExtendedString.prototype` not `%StringPrototype` as the [[prototype]] for the newly created exotic String object:

> 8. Set the [[Prototype]] [internal slot](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots) of `S` to `prototype`.

Comment: Must be an old V8 bug, I'll see if I can locate it.

Comment: Can't locate any bugs on this, but I think it's safe to assume it was a former bug in V8.