# Get javascript class name or typeof in parent constructor

Tags: javascript

I have two classes in Javascript like this:

```
class Parent {
    constructor(){
        console.log(typeof this);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
}
```

In the Parent class, I would like to know what class instantiated it. However, typeof just returns object. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: What exactly do you need this for? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/183280).

Comment: I intend to let the Parent class handle methods like save and get, and unless anything else is specified, it will look in tables that are named lowercase of the calling class. So if I instantiate a child, and run child.save() i'll let the Parent.save method save the object to a table called "child"

Comment: I would recommend to pass the table name explicitly as a parameter to the parent constructor. Relying on the child constructor name has several problems: it might not work in pre-ES6 environments, it breaks the LSP, and there might be anonymous subclasses or duplicate names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.constructor` will return the constructor function with which the objet was created. You could access `this.constructor.name` if you need a string.

```js
class Parent {
    constructor(){
        console.log(this.constructor.name);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
}

new Child(); // Child
new Parent(); // Parent
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ES6 classes, [`new.target`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32450516/1048572) is what you are looking for. But notice that it's usually an antipattern to let a constructor's behaviour depend on particular child classes.