# ES6 What does super() actually do in constructor function?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, ecmascript-6, super

!
Hola, amigos. I have this little class inheritance structure

```
class Point {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    toString() {
        return '(' + this.x + ', ' + this.y + ')';
    }
}

class ColorPoint extends Point {
    constructor(x, y, color) {
        super(x, y); 
        this.color = color;
    }
    toString() {
        return super.toString() + ' in ' + this.color; 
    }
}

let newObj = new ColorPoint(25, 8, 'green');
```

It compiles to [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wsne0ya1/1/)

I get how it works in es6 in a silly way.
But could somebody explain how does it work under the hood in es5. 
In a simpler form.

Comment: It invokes `constructor()` on the parent class. At the simple level, there's really only so much to say. Is there something in particular you're curious about?

Comment: @SMcCrohan, maybe try to explain not in a simpler form. It invokes constructor() on the parent class - that was already grasped. But how does it invokes it? How does these arguments get passed from subclass to superclass through super() . I understand these steps (maybe) but not the actual mechanics behind them. Why cant we just use `.__proto__` and `.call` or `.apply`?

Comment: Can anyone explain what happens here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54685556/why-doesnt-reassigning-a-super-method-result-in-that-reassigned-method-being-ca in context of super

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`super(…);` is basically sugar for `this = new ParentConstructor(…);`. Where `ParentConstructor` is the extended class, and `this =` is the initialisation of the `this` keyword (well, given that that's forbidden syntax, there's a bit more than sugar to it). And actually it will inherit from the proper [`new.target.prototype`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32458960/1048572) instead of `ParentConstructor.prototype` like it would from `new`. So no, how it works under the hood does not compare to ES5 at all, this is really a new feature in ES6 classes (and finally enables us to properly subclass builtins).

Comment: Well this shed some light on. Thank you.

Comment: `function SubClass() {
    return SuperClass.call(this)
}`

Would this not set the prototype correctly and still remain within the constructs of ES5?

Comment: @niagr Yes, that's the ES5 way.