# class vs prototype Array.isArray

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, prototype

I have always been told “Classes are just syntactic sugar for prototypes.”

But in this example this shows this isn't true.

```
function SubArray() {}
SubArray.prototype = new Array( );
console.log(Array.isArray(new SubArray()))  // false
```

and the same example with classes.

```
SubArray = class extends Array{}
console.log(Array.isArray(new SubArray()))  // true
```

Funnily `instanceof` works fine on both `new SubArray instanceof Array`.
Why isn’t `Array.isArray` returning `true` with prototype here?

Comment: classes are syntactic sugar for the prototypal pattern in javascript

Comment: class are mostly syntax sugar for prototypes, the main difference is that classes can extend built-ins while regular prototypes can't. http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html#subclassing-built-in-constructors

Comment: Because inheriting from builtins is one of the few bits where classes are more than sugar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419713/are-es6-classes-just-syntactic-sugar-for-the-prototypal-pattern-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are the es6 classes really semantic sugar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48036853/1048572)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you did not write the code that `class` is actually syntactic sugar of:

```js
function SubArray () {
  if (!(new.target)) {
    throw new TypeError("Class constructor SubArray cannot be invoked without 'new'")
  }

  return Reflect.construct(Array, arguments, new.target)
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(SubArray.prototype, Array.prototype)
Object.setPrototypeOf(SubArray, Array)

console.log(Array.isArray(new SubArray())) // true
```

The above should behave identically to the example you provided using `class` syntax. Unfortunately not all of this behavior can be accurately reproduced without other ES6 constructs like `new.target` and `Reflect.construct()`, but at least those aren't necessarily required in order to produce your desired behavior:

```js
function SubArray () {
  if (!(this instanceof SubArray)) {
    throw new TypeError("Class constructor SubArray cannot be invoked without 'new'")
  }

  return Array.apply(this, arguments)
}

SubArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype)
// the line below is not necessary for Array.isArray()
// but accurately reproduces behavior of `class SubArray extends Array {}`
SubArray.__proto__ = Array // implementation hack if Object.setPrototypeOf() is not available

console.log(Array.isArray(new SubArray())) // true
```

The key here is that you delegate construction of the instantiated object to the `Array` constructor in order to initialize the object as an Array exotic object. So hypothetically, all that's *strictly* necessary is the following:

```js
function SubArray () {
  return Array.call(this)
}

console.log(Array.isArray(new SubArray())) // true
```

But of course, you won't have access to `Array.prototype` methods in this case, so you should stick to `class` syntax or the second example if you have to support ES5.

#### Edit

I did some tinkering and I personally think this is a horrible idea, but if you want to emulate `class` as closely as possible in ES5, you can opt out of `strict mode` in order to have access to `arguments.caller`:

```js
// DON'T ACTUALLY DO THIS
// just for demonstration purposes

function SubArray () {
  // this is about as close as you can get to new.target in ES5
  if (!(this instanceof SubArray) && !(arguments.caller && this instanceof arguments.caller)) {
    throw new TypeError("Class constructor SubArray cannot be invoked without 'new'")
  }

  return Array.apply(this, arguments)
}

SubArray.prototype.__proto__ = Array.prototype
SubArray.__proto__ = Array

// we want FooBar to extend SubArray sloppily
function FooBar () {
  if (!(this instanceof SubArray) && !(arguments.caller && this instanceof arguments.caller)) {
    throw new TypeError("Class constructor FooBar cannot be invoked without 'new'")
  }

  return SubArray.apply(this, arguments)
}

FooBar.prototype.__proto__ = SubArray.prototype
FooBar.__proto__ = SubArray

try {
  SubArray()
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.toString())
}

console.log(new SubArray(1, 2, 3))

try {
  FooBar()
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.toString())
}

console.log(new FooBar(1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the steps to perform [`Array.isArray()`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.3.2):

> IsArray ( argument )
>
> The abstract operation IsArray takes one argument argument, and
>   performs the following steps:
>
> ```
> If Type(argument) is not Object, return false.
> If argument is an Array exotic object, return true.
> If argument is a Proxy exotic object, then
>     If the value of the [[ProxyHandler]] internal slot of argument is null, throw a TypeError exception.
>     Let target be the value of the [[ProxyTarget]] internal slot of argument.
>     Return IsArray(target).
> Return false.
> ```

Your example fails at the step "If argument is an Array exotic object, return true." because it doesn't have it's **own** length property.

```js
function SubArray() {}
SubArray.prototype = new Array( );
console.log(Array.isArray(new SubArray())) // false


const sa = new SubArray();
console.log(typeof sa); // object
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(sa, "length")); // undefined
```

Comment: In practice setting .length doesn't seem to make `Array.isArray` return true though

Comment: An object doesn't become an Array exotic object just because it has an own length property.

Comment: @William @bergi I'm not trying to imply that setting a length causes an Object to become an Array.  I'm saying that's where the Object fails the `isArray` function.  Besides, setting an explicit `length` would create a `configurable` property.  Array exotics have non-configurable `length`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to rlemon in chat you can do something similar to what Patrick did with out Reflect and should theoretically have IE11 support.

```
function Foo() {
    const arr = new Array(...arguments);
    arr.__proto__ = Foo.prototype;
    return arr;
}

Foo.prototype.constructor = Foo;

Foo.prototype.__proto__ = Array.prototype;

Array.isArray( new Foo(123) )
```

Comment: I don't see what the point of avoiding `Reflect` is here. You're still using several ES6 constructs in order to implement this, and this does not emulate what `class extends` does.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts probably makes sense to use `__proto__`.  Usuing caniuse.com it appears IE11(some still support this saddly) supports `__proto__` but not Reflect.

Comment: Yeah, but `Foo` is not a constructor in this implementation. It completely discards the instantiated object created with `new Foo` and returns a different one constructed with `new Array`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts in practice what does this mean?  `instanceof` and the `constructor` are correct.

Comment: `class Bar extends Foo {} console.log(new Bar() instanceof Bar) // false!!`

Answer (score 0):

This method makes use of iframes and allows you to extend the class if you choose using class extend fuctionality.

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

frames[frames.length - 1].document.write(
  "<script>parent.SubArray = Array;<\/script>"
);

SubArray.prototype.__proto__ = Array.prototype;
SubArray.__proto__ = Array;
console.log(Array.isArray(new SubArray()));
console.log(new SubArray() instanceof Array);
console.log(new SubArray() instanceof SubArray);

SubArray2 = class extends SubArray {} 

console.log(new SubArray2() instanceof SubArray)
```

Answer (score -2):

ES5 way of doing things do not allow you to properly to inherit from `Array`. ES6 makes it work properly.