# Why is the internal implementation of React.Component a function and not an ES6 class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class

I've been digging into React's [codebase](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v16.8.4/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js) and I discovered that when you write `class App extends React.Component`, you are actually extending an object created by the following function:

```js
function Component (props, context, updater) {
  this.props = props;
  this.context = context;
  this.refs = {};
  // We initialize the default updater but the real one gets injected by the
  // renderer.
  this.updater = updater || ReactNoopUpdateQueue ;
}

Component.prototype.isReactComponent = {};

Component.prototype.setState = function(partialState, callback) {
  this.updater.enqueueSetState(this, partialState, callback, 'setState')
}

Component.prototype.forceUpdate = function(callback) {
  this.updater.enqueueForceUpdate(this, callback, 'forceUpdate');
}
```

What is the advantage of creating classes this way as opposed to just writing an ES6 class?

Comment: The advantage is that this code runs in environments that don't support `class` syntax without having to preprocess the code. It produces the same result as using `class`.

Comment: Not sure why they aren't using Babel to transpile it down ...

Comment: Maybe so that it supports being extended in ES5 style?

Comment: An ES6 class it's only syntactic sugar for the developer at the end a `class` will be converted to a function

Comment: @OsDev No, it won't be converted to different syntax. And classes are [not only syntactic sugar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48036928/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi Actually, in the end, it's an abstraction of prototypal inheritance, so syntactic sugar for people that come from the OOP world

Answer (score 1):

https://caniuse.com/#search=es6%20class

This has to do with browser compatibility.  Ensuring that the code can run where the `class` sytax is not supported without having to transpile with something like Babel.

Comment: This is a likely reason, but can you prove that it's the reason why React specifically is doing this?

Comment: It's probably already been transpiled with babel to ES5 from their dev environment. =)

Comment: No, OP linked to the source code not to the transpiled code.