# What does this TypeScript syntax mean?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am watching a video about RxJS and have come across some TypeScript syntax I've not seen before. It doesn't matter that it's RxJS, it's a generic question, but I thought I'd just add that it was RxJS.

It's the call to `super()` in this that I don't understand:

```
class MyObservable extends Rx.Observable {
    constructor(initialValue) {
        super(observer) => {
            observer.next(initialValue);
            this.observer = observer;
        }
    }
}
```

The video goes on to point out that this is not a good way to extend observable functionality, but that's not what I'm interested in anyway. I'm interested in the call to `super()`: what's going on here? The best that I can come up with is that it is shadowing the base class's constructor, but I'm not sure. Can anyone elucidate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 What does super() actually do in constructor function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582147/es6-what-does-super-actually-do-in-constructor-function)

Comment: I'm guessing it's a typo, and that it's supposed to be passing an anonymous function to `super`, and the parenthesis is misplaced. Likely it should be `super(observer => { ... })`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely a typo. The [constructor for Rx.Observable](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-constructor-constructor) takes a function argument, which itself takes a Subscriber - an object with 'next' (as confirmed by your code), and 'error'/'complete' methods, although those aren't used in the code above. This was almost certainly meant to be

```
class MyObservable extends Rx.Observable {
    constructor(initialValue) {
        super((observer) => {
            observer.next(initialValue);
            this.observer = observer;
        });
    }
}
```

This also makes sense from what the video is describing, about extending Rx functionality - you're effectively 'capturing' the observer and passing it an additional initial value, before setting it to `this.observer` and letting `Rx.Observable` continue to do its thing.

Comment: Yes, I just checked with WebStorm and this is indeed a syntax error. Surprised it made it into the video actually.