# Why doesn't reassigning a super method result in that reassigned method being called later?

Tags: javascript

In the below constructor, `super.say` is reassigned to a new function. When `.say()` is called on the instance, the new function is called. But when calling a *different* method on the instance which calls `super.say`, the new function is *not* called - the original function on the parent `C` class is called instead. Why is there a difference?

```js
class C {
  say() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}
class D extends C {
  constructor() {
    super()
    super.say = function() {
      console.log('changed');
    }
  }
  shout() {
    super.say()
  }
}

let d = new D()
// changed
d.say()
// hello
d.shout()
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance
Well, what I have is a different question (though they seems to be the same by titile), could you please remove the ":duplicate" tag?

Comment: Your original question text was "I am wondering what does super exactly represent for. Could anyone please show me the mechanism behind it?", thus the closure - the edited question is much more specific as to what you're asking about, thanks.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks. The 'what is ...' expression is something too universal and I shouldn't use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that `super` is *syntax*. It’s *not* a function call with a magical name (although that’s what it looks like!).

See the grammar productions for [`SuperProperty`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-SuperProperty) and [`SuperCall`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-SuperCall) in the ECMAScript spec:

- `SuperProperty` covers things like `super.someProperty` and `super[someExpression]`.
- `SuperCall` covers `super()` and `super(someArgument)`.

Comment: Another ECMAScript example of this is [dynamic `import()`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import). It looks like a function call, but it isn’t!

Comment: Specifically the internal operation MakeSuperPropertyReference shows how this operates: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-makesuperpropertyreference. TBH though I am unclear on why it was decided to allow use of SuperProperty as an assignable reference.

Answer (score 2):

Now I am not 100% but here is my 2 cents on what is going on

`super` is acting pretty super weird, from the looks of it appeared as `super` acts different thing in different operation, and that is exactly what is happening. Suspecting it earlier I tried to `console.log(super)` and error happened. When I googled to find why? I came across the explanation, along the lines of "its a `keyword` like `var` and you cannot log `var` keyword as it is". So that tells us `super` is not your regular object.

What happens is when you do some thing like

```
constructor() {
  super();
}
```

Here `super()` will actually call the constructor of prototype C, which you can see when you `console.log(C)` which results into

```
C = {
  constructor: f(),
  say: f()
}
```

But as soon as you do

```
class D extends C {
  constructor(id) {
    super();

    super.say2 = function() {
      console.log('changed ' + this.id);
    }
}
```

Here `super.say2` actually refers to `this` or instance of class D (Holy Mother of Bejesus, how can somebody get away with something like that)

I changed the name to `say2` to verify exactly that, see your code below which I changed to test that

```
class C {
  say() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}
class D extends C {
  constructor(id) {
    super();

    super.say2 = function() {
      console.log('changed ' + this.id);
    }
    console.log(this)
    console.log(D.prototype)
  }
  shout() {
    super.say()
  }
}

let d = new D(1)
d.say()
d.shout()
```

When you run this code what you will see in console is

[image]

Here `say2` is actually in the instance of D, and where is `say` of C prototype? well, see for yourself its still there UNCHANGED

[image]

So in summary when you call `super.say()` it calls the function of C prototype, when you do `super.say = function()` in constructor, it assigns it to current instance of D

At best from further testing what I came to know is super is evaluated as something called `intermedia.value` because when I did this

```
shout() {
    super.say2()
}
```

It gave error `Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).say2 is not a function`

**Summary**

- When you called `d.say()` It actually referred to `say` function of
  instance `d`
- When you called `d.shout()` It referred to `say` method of class `C`

God, just when I thought I know JS