# What's happening when inheriting a Proxy of Class (Function) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, es6-proxy

I want to inherit a function with proxied constructor, like SubB below;

```
const Base = function () {};
Base.prototype.baseMethod = function () { return 'base method'; }

class SubA extends (new Proxy(Base, {})) {
    subMethod () { return 'sub method'; }
}

const handler = { construct: (target, args) => new target(...args) };
class SubB extends (new Proxy(Base, handler)) {
    subMethod () { return 'sub method'; }
}
```

However, it does not work collectly; Subclass methods seems not to be bound in SubB.

```
(new SubA()).baseMethod(); //=> "base method"
(new SubB()).baseMethod(); //=> "base method"

(new SubA()).subMethod(); //=> "sub method"
(new SubB()).subMethod();
  //=> Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).subMethod is not a function
```

What's happening in class SubB and how can I fix it (or is it possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring [`new.target`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32450516/1048572), which is why the instance that your proxied constructor creates always inherits from the `Base` (the `target` in the proxy handler) only, and not from the `SubB`.

You should use [`Reflect.construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct) as the default action of the [`construct` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/construct):

```
const handler = {
  construct(target, args, newTarget) {
    return Reflect.construct(target, args, newTarget);
  }
};
class SubB extends (new Proxy(Base, handler)) {
  subMethod () { return 'sub method'; }
}
```