# How to use a Proxy in javascript to capture a constructor while maintaining the prototype chain?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constructor, es6-proxy

I want to create a constructor object whose inheritance works as normal, but capture the constructor so I can manipulate the instance object.  Using `Proxy()` *almost* solves this, but it seems to screw up the inheritance.  Note the following example without a proxy:

```
> const B = function() {}
undefined
> B.name
'B'
> class C extends B {}
[Function: C]
> B.prototype == C.prototype.__proto__
true
> var instance = new C()
undefined
> C.prototype == instance.__proto__
true
> instance.__proto__
C {}
```

Now, if I add a proxy to capture `construct(target,args)`, it will correctly capture the constructor, but it doesn't preserve things exactly as it would without the proxy.  Note that all the constructor does is print a message to the console noting its capture.  But otherwise (I think) it should react the same.  However, when I create a class to extend the proxied function, it seems like the extended function is missing entirely.  Note the last four lines give different results than above.

```
> const handler = { construct(target,args) {
... console.log('Captured!'); return new target(...args); } }
undefined
> const proxy_B = new Proxy(B, handler)
undefined
> proxy_B.name
'B'
> class C2 extends proxy_B {}
[Function: C2]
> proxy_B.prototype == C2.prototype.__proto__
true
> var instance2 = new C2()
Captured!
undefined
> C2.prototype == instance2.__proto__
false
> instance2.__proto__
B {}
```

What am I doing wrong?  How do I write the proxy to properly handle this case?

Comment: It's not clear in your example why you aren't just using the `constructor()` function on `C` to 'manipulate the instance object`. This seems like an XY problem

Comment: Sorry to be clear, I am a middle-man.  B is an API object and I don't control how clients use it.  They may choose to subclass it or not.  This is just an example of how the proxy doesn't do what I would expect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your handler doesn't handle the [`new.target`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32458960/1048572). Notice that the `target` of your proxy is `B`, and when you `return new target` then you'll construct a `B` instance not a `C` instance.

Instead of approximating the construction behaviour with `new`, use the `Reflect` object (in particular [`Reflect.construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct)) to use the *exact* default construction behaviour and pass all the arguments of the trap method:

```
const handler = {
    construct(target, args, newtarget) {
//                          ^^^^^^^^^
        console.log('Captured!');
        return Reflect.construct(target, args, newtarget);
//                                             ^^^^^^^^^
    }
};
```

Comment: That's a bingo!  Works perfectly.

Comment: I searched like 4 hours for an answer to this problem. How can we make that more prominent on the internet?

Comment: Maybe start by upvoting the question? ;-)