# ES6, Must call super before accessing 'this' and defining constant in derived class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I want to define a constant in base class, then override it in sub-classes, how should I do?

The catch is that, for my specific case, this constant is a `new Map()`, and the result will be consulted with during constructor:

```
class Cmd0 {
  constructor(name, arg1, arg2 = null) {
    this.name = name;
    this.arg1 = arg1;
    this.arg2 = arg2;
  }
. . .
}

class Cmd extends Cmd0 {
  constructor(name, arg1, arg2 = null) {
    myMap =  Somehow.getMyMap() // defined in sub-classes
    if (!myMap.has(name)) { super(null, null, null); return } // fail the constructor
    super(name, arg1, arg2)
  }
}

class SubCmd1 extends Cmd {

  Usage() {
    if (this.name) return null
    else return "cmd sub1 bla bla bla"
  }
}

class SubCmd2 extends Cmd {

  Usage() {
    if (this.name) return null
    else return "cmd sub2 bla bla bla"
  }
}
```

Both `SubCmd1` and `SubCmd2` need to define their own version of `getMyMap()` to be consumed in base constructor, before `this` can be accessed.

The `getMyMap()` method would be in the format of,

```
getMyMap() {
  return new Map()
    .set("name1", arg11, arg12)
    .set("name2", arg21, arg22)
}
```

Is it possible to somehow make it work?
You can start from - https://jsbin.com/xubijosuro/edit?js,console,output

PS. Here is how I'm using `SubCmd1`, `SubCmd2`, etc:

```
const cli = new CliCaseA(name, argsObj) 
const usage = cli.Usage() 
if (usage) { console.log(`Usage:\n\n${usage}`) process.exit() }
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the `getMyMap` methods, so we can see what they depend on?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, updated. Basically I wanted to define `getMyMap` methods as `static`, but don't know how to access them in base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a static property of the class (or getter or method) that you can access even before the `super()` call using [`new.target`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32450516/1048572):

```
class MappedCmd extends Cmd {
  constructor(name, arg1, arg2 = null) {
    const myMap = new.target.getMyMap();
//                ^^^^^^^^^^
    …
    super(name, arg1, arg2)
  }
  static getMyMap() {
    return new Map(); // to be overridden or extended in the subclasses
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bergi. Can the constructor you provided be moved from `SubCmdX` level to `Cmd` level, as all of them will otherwise using the exact same code? Also, do you know if there is any site that I can try out the above ES6 code? I tried https://jsbin.com/xubijosuro/edit?js,console,output, but got _"TypeError: .new.target.getMyMap is not a function"_. Is there any place that you can demonstrate that the ES6 code is working (_without transpiling_)?

Comment: If I turn `getMyMap()` into `static`, as in https://jsbin.com/fihiqayuki/1/edit?js,console,output, then I'll get "_ReferenceError: myMap is not defined_" instead.

Comment: The code in your jsbin is missing the `static` and `const` keywords.