# Check if child class has constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, instance

This is my first question on Stackoverflow so please dont run over me like a bulldozer if i did something wrong :)

I need to know if its possible in JavaScript classes to know, if the child has provided a constructor.

E.g.

```
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Child has constructor:', /* Magic here */)
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {}

new Child()
```

Expected output: `Child has constructor: false`

Vs:

```
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Child has constructor:', /* Magic here */)
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
}

new Child()
```

Expected output: `Child has constructor: true`

Background: I would like to have a class that behaves differently when it was extended than if it was used directly.
Since Childs should provide the Parent different informations than if it was used directly.

Comment: The only way i could think of is by using .toString() and check if the class has a constructor :/

Comment: Ok yea i feared that :/ Its not possible. Probably a class is defacto a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

The `class` syntax in JavaScript is just a syntax suger of a normal `function`.

Take this ES6 example:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor(value){
    this.example = value;
  }
  parentMethod(){
    console.log('parent:', this.example);
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  childMethod(){
    console.log('children:', this.example);
  }
}

const parent = new Parent('Hello');
const child = new Child('World');

parent.parentMethod();
child.childMethod();

console.log(parent.constructor);
console.log(child.constructor);
```

As you can see, even if you don't explicitly define a constructor, a class will always have a constructor.

The above could roughly translate into the below ES5 code which does not yet support `class` syntax:

```js
function Parent(value){
  this.example = value;
}

Object.defineProperties(Parent.prototype, {
  parentMethod: {
    writable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    value: function(){
      console.log('parent:', this.example);
    }
  }
});

function Child(value){
  Parent.call(this, value);
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
Child.prototype = Object.defineProperties(Child.prototype, {
  childMethod: {
    writable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    value: function(){
      console.log('child:', this.example);
    }
  }
});

var parent = new Parent('Hello');
var child = new Child('World');

parent.parentMethod();
child.childMethod();

console.log(parent.constructor);
console.log(child.constructor);
```

As you can see:

1. A `class` is merely just a function.
2. The `.constructor` is always assigned.

Hence, there is no way for you to check if child class has a constructor because constructor is always there.

Even if you can do it (which you can't), the Parent will not know beforehand what class will extend it, so it will not know whether or not a future child will have a constructor or not.

Comment: Exactly what i feared. Thanks for explaining it :)
Ps: Using .toString() would be ugly but still work, right?

Comment: By using this in the Parent:
`console.log(!!this.constructor.toString().match(/constructor\s*\(/))`

Comment: @Freefant no it won't work because (1) the child could have something like `const constructor =  'hello'`, then you'll get a false positive, (2) when you transpile the code using babel (or something like that), the `.toString()` might give you a different value depending on the transpiler output.

Answer (score 2):

You could add one parameter to the Parent constructor that is false by default and then when you call the super inside the Child class you pass true for this parameter.

```js
class Parent {
  constructor(called = false) {
    console.log('Child has constructor:', called)
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super(true)
  }
}

class ChildTwo extends Parent {}

new Child()
new ChildTwo()
```

Comment: But then i would not be able to use the Parent class independently for other usages right?
For example if i expect the user to provide a object as Parameter.

Comment: You can use parent independently, `const parent = new Parent()`, the only issue would be if you wanted to pass more parameters to the parent

Comment: Yea thats what i would like to do. If Parent was used directly, have different behaviour than if it was extended.

Comment: if you want you can declare the Parent constructor as so `class Parent {
 constructor({ called = false, ...args } = {}){
  console.log(called, args)
 }}` then you can use whichever arguments you want and also pass `({ called: true })` from children

Comment: Mhh interesting. The object approach could work. I will give it a try and give my feedback :)

Comment: Okay i think i will do it this way i guess

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know if its possible in JavaScript classes to know, if the child has provided a constructor.

There are no classes without a constructor. Some classes might have an implicit constructor (no `constructor` in the `class` syntax), but you cannot - and should not - detect that.

> I would like to have a class that behaves differently when it was extended than if it was used directly

You can distinguish a `new Child` from a `new Parent` call using [`new.target == Parent`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32450516/1048572).

> Childs should provide the Parent different information than if it was used directly.

That's a bad idea. Your parent constructor should have an interface that doesn't care about who is using it. I would suggest to either

- never use your parent class directly, but extend it yourself and provide that class for default usage. It can handle the different information.
- make the parent class accept different kinds of information, i.e. overload its interface. Distinguish what information you were given, and behave accordingly. However, it should not matter whether the information was given directly by a user or produced by a child class.